# How to send a json response for certificate expired exception in Spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have Self Signed Certificates and I have implemented the custom trust manager to check the validity of the client certificate. It throws exception on handshake regarding expired certificate. Is there a way to send a JSON response to the client?

```
public TrustManager[] sslContextConfiguration() throws GeneralSecurityException
  {
    // Create our custom trust manager to validate the certificates
    TrustManager[] trustManager = new TrustManager[]
        {
            new X509TrustManager()
            {
              @Override
              public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
              {
                return new X509Certificate[]{};
              }

              /**
               * This method checks the validity of the certificates of the server in trust store
               * This will be used when Embedded SW will be a client to the remote services
               *
               * @param certs array of certificates
               * @param authType authentication type
               */
              @Override
              public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                  throws CertificateException
              {
                checkCertificateValidity(certs);
              }
              /**
               * This method checks the validity of the certificates of the clients in trust store
               * This will be used when Embedded SW will be a server to external softwares
               *
               * @param certs array of certificates
               * @param authType authentication type
               */
              @Override
              public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                  throws CertificateException
              {
                checkCertificateValidity(certs);
              }
            }
        };

    return trustManager;
  }   


  /**
   * Method to check the validity / expiry of the certificates
   *
   * @param certs
   */
  public void checkCertificateValidity(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs)
      throws CertificateException
  {
    for (X509Certificate certificate : certs)
    {
        //Explicit Check for Certificate Validity This method throws exception

        certificate.checkValidity();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Post the code snippet where you are throwing the exception.

Comment: You can use `Gson` by Google Java library to serialize and deserialize Java objects to JSON.